# JAXB Java Marshalling error

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I am trying to marshal a simple Java class with JAXB and I am running into errors. I am looking for advice on fixing the errors bellow
These are the errors:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\file.xml (Access is denied)]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at JAXBExample.main(JAXBExample.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\file.xml (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

The errors come when I attempt to run the class for JAXB marshaling. It was downloaded from a tutorial website (http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) so It should be correct.

This is the Marshal class:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class JAXBExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Customer customer = new Customer();
      customer.setId(100);
      customer.setName("mkyong");
      customer.setAge(29);

      try {

        File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, file);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

The Marshaling class references a Customer class. 
This is the customer class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    String name;
    int age;
    int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have the permissions to read that file? Or the file.xml is open somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

The error appears to have nothing to do with XML - you simply don't have access to the file that you are trying to open.

Try removing the "C:\\" so that the file will be in the working directory instead of the top of the C drive.